# Clicking submit button indirectly wont set $_POST['submit']

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to get an image to insert into my filesystem:
When a user clicks a button it triggers the file input of a form, when a file is selected it triggers the clicking of the forms submit button, which posts it to the PHP processing script.

Currently the script is not recognising $_POST['submit'] as being set. I can't figure out why?

HTML:

```
<div id="toolbar">
            <!-- custom toolbar: linking all buttons to Quill -->
            <span class="ql-formats">
                 <button class="ql-clean"></button>
                 <button class="ql-upload"><i class="fas fa-images"></i></button>
            </span>
</div>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1" runat="server" name="imageForm">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="imgInp">
    <button type="submit" id="sub2" name="submit">Save</button>
    <span id="result"></span>
</form>
```

JS:

```
//linking button to input field
$('.ql-upload').click(function()
{
    $("#imgInp").trigger("click");
});

// submitting form when file is chosen
$(document).ready(function()
{
    document.getElementById("imgInp").onchange = function()
    {
        $("#sub2").trigger("click");
    };
});
```

PHP:

```
session_start();
require_once('db.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
........ etc
```

Comment: To submit the button itself as a form element use `<input type="submit">`  instead

Comment: Firstly add your following code : `//linking button to input field
$('.ql-upload').click(function()
{
    $("#imgInp").trigger("click");
});` inside `$(document).ready(function()`

Comment: The question title sounds as if clicking the button manually *does* set `$_POST['submit']` but afaik that's not the case.

Comment: Also use `document.getElementById("imgInp").addEventListener("change", function() { ... }` instead

Comment: @JitendraAhuja Or rather `$("#imgInp").on("change", ...`

Comment: @ChrisG Yes using jQuery would be even easy

Comment: it still does not set @peter

Comment: Still not set @JitendraAhuja

Comment: Wait, where is your element with class `ql-upload` ? Add full code here, if its not

Comment: @jitendraAhuja Q has been updated :)

Comment: Have you tried the above `document.getElementById("imgInp").addEventListener("change", function() { alert("inside");  $("#sub2").trigger("click"); }` ?  If not then try this.. and check if alert occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking if `$_POST['submit']` is set. I recommend checking if the request is a POST.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // ... Handle your form
}
```